# Custom message for min and max in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to get the customized message for min => 0 in yii2.

```
 ['landed_at', 'number', 'min' => 0, 'message' => 'Must be greater than 0'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tooSmall instead of message like

```
 ['landed_at', 'number', 'min' => 0, 'tooSmall' => 'The value must be greater than Zero(0).'],
```